# Regex to match all acronyms

Tags: c#, regex

I'm looking for a regex to match acronyms like N.A.S.A. but also N.A.S.A without ending point.
This solution [RegEx to match acronyms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35076016/regex-to-match-acronyms) works but only for acronyms ending with '.'

Any idea to match 'N.A.S.A' AND 'N.A.S.A.' ?

Comment: The acronym isn't valid syntax if just the last letter has no period. Regardless, pleas show what you have tried so far.

Comment: NASA is classically written with without any periods...

Comment: In spanish acronyms of plurals are slightly different. "Comunidades Autonomas" acronym is "CC.AA."

Answer (score 0):

The `\b(?:[a-zA-Z]\.){2,}` solution repeats the pattern inside the non-capturing group 2 or more times. You need to make sure `.` is not required at the end:

```
\b[a-zA-Z](?:\.[a-zA-Z])+\b
```

To also match the `.` after the last letter add `\.?`:

```
\b[a-zA-Z](?:\.[a-zA-Z])+\b\.?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JBvKT7/1)

**NOTE** To match uppercase letters only, remove `a-z`.

The pattern matches

- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `[a-zA-Z]` - 1 ASCII letter
- `(?:\.[a-zA-Z])+` - 1 or more  (so, at least 2 letters will be required) repetitions of

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `[a-zA-Z]` - 1 ASCII letter
- `\b` - trailing word boundary
- `\.?` - 1 or 0 `.` chars.

**P.S.**: To enable any Unicode letter support, replace `[a-zA-Z]` with `\p{L}` and `[A-Z]` with `\p{Lu}`.

Answer (score -1):

Never mind ;)
I did it like this : `\b([a-z0-9]\.){1,}[a-z0-9]?\b`

Comment: Acronyms usually refer to words, so you may consider removing the `0-9`

Comment: This won't match 2-letter acronyms.